# My Visual Studio 2022 consistently gives me errors saying that the GLchar variable type is undefined

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-c++, opengl-4

I've been working on a little bit of code recently using the WIN32 API, GL.h, and GLU.h. I recently figured out that if I define a variable with the type GLchar my Visual Studio will give me an error saying that GLchar is an undefined identifier. Here's the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLchar" is undefined    RendGL  C:\Dev\RendGL\GLFunc.h  13`
```

Here's an MRE:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>

int main() {
   const GLchar* string = "Example";
   return 0;
}
```

This code would result in:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "GLchar" is undefined    RendGL        C:\Dev\RendGL\GLFunc.h    13
```

I've scoured the internet for an answer, but haven't been able to find anything. Most of the posts that detail similar issues to mine have answers telling them to include a loading library or utility library before their GL, but I'm not using a loading library or utility library.

Comment: IDK the answer, GL headers are weird. But the correct type for a string literal is `char` in any case, so just replace `GLchar` with `char`.

Comment: GLchar isn't defined in the #include <GL\gl.h> provided by microsoft (it is a later addition to openGL)

it is defined as `typedef char GLchar;`

all the later stuff is defined in https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/api/GL/glext.h

for reference, microsoft's gl.h header hasn't had new additions since the later 90's early 2000's i think.

Comment: So could I just use char instead of GLchar?

Comment: @FulltimeNerd yes, up to you though. You can either make the typedef yourself, create and include the glext.h, or just use char's.